# Am getting this Error 404 on php

Tags: php

Hi has just started learning php I had created a log in script and it was working fine now all of a sudden I am getting this error . Need some help.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1op897320mledpy/2015-07-14_0638.png?dl=0

```
<?php 
require_once 'connection.php'; 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{ 
    $username =$_POST['username']; 
    $firstname =$_POST['firstname']; 
    $lastname =$_POST['lastname']; 
    $email =$_POST['email']; 
    $password = md5($_POST[' $query = "INSERT INTO user_tbl(username,firstname,lastname,email,password) VALUES ('$username','$firstname','$lastname','$clean_email','$password')"; 
    $result= mysqli_query($connection,$query); 
    if (!$result) 
        { 
            die("Query failed" . mysqli_error()); 
        } 
    } 
    header("location: email_activation_showpage.php"); 
?>
```

Comment: add some code to this

Comment: The registration process file ..  <?php

require_once 'connection.php';

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 $username  =$_POST['username'];
 $firstname =$_POST['firstname'];
 $lastname  =$_POST['lastname'];
 $email     =$_POST['email'];
 $password  =  md5($_POST['
 $query = "INSERT INTO user_tbl(username,firstname,lastname,email,password) VALUES ('$username','$firstname','$lastname','$clean_email','$password')";

 $result= mysqli_query($connection,$query);

 if (!$result) {

  die("Query failed" . mysqli_error());

 }
 
 
}
 header("location: email_activation_showpage.php");


?>

Comment: Does `email_activation_showpage.php` file exist?

Comment: what are you trying to do with this? `$password = md5($_POST[' $query = "INSERT INTO user_tbl(username,firstname,lastname,email,password) VALUES ('$username','$firstname','$lastname','$clean_email','$password')"; ` It makes no sense

Comment: @RiyanZaman check my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31398694/4595675) posted below

Answer (score 0):

That means the page not found.
make sure you type the correct exact path to your page in the link field.
and make sure of capital or small letters in the path and the extensions too.
example 
if you put your page in www file and the page called hello.php
you should write in the link 
localhost/hello.php

Answer (score 0):

I'd hazard a guess that the "email_activation_showpage.php" script you are redirecting to at the end either doesn't exist, is mis-spelled or not in the same directory as the script you are running

Answer (score 0):

**ERROR 404:** Suugests that the File you had located Didn,t exists.Please Check the File and Try again.

**Error on** : Header('location:XXXXXXXX');